# How to add code lines when calling a function depending on an iterator on Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, autocomplete

I am trying to test many ML models using `keras.models.Sequential`.

My idea is that once I have an iterator that looks like `[num_layers, num_units_per_layers]`, for example `[(1, 64),(2, (64,128))]`, to create a script using a kind of for loop running the iterator to be able to create a `keras` sequential model with the number of layers and units in each step of the iterator.

This is what I am trying:

```
it = [[(1, 128),(2, (64,128)), (3,(128,64,256))]]
for layers, units in it:
    model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(units[0])
        #How to get another layers here when layers > 1.
    ])
```

But I am stuck when adding new layers automatically. To sum up, what I want in each step of the iterator is the `keras` model represented by its values.
Is there any way to do this?

For example, when `layers = 2` and `units = (64,128)` the code should look like:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64),
    layers.Dense(128)
])
```

If `layers = 1` and `units = 128` the code must be:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(128)
])
```

Comment: You should fix your indentation.

Comment: So is this in the case that there is more than one unit or more than one layer? Can you give a sample of one layer versus two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first issue is the way you set up `it`. The way you're doing it makes it a single list, where you want a list of n lists (here n is 3). If you define `it` as follows, you can extract `layers, units` the way you are looking for.

```
it = [[1,[128]],[2,(64,128)],[3,(128,64,256)]]
```

If you want a model with one layer, you need to put the number of units in brackets, or it won't work well with the other architectures (because of indexing). Next, there are some necessary tweaks to the code that I would suggest. First I would use a different way to build a Sequential model (shown below). Then, you would need to define your input shape otherwise the model will not know how to build. Finally, just create an output layer for each model outside the hidden layer generator loop.

I wrote this toy problem to fit your idea of iterating through models for 10 training samples and one input dimension and one output dimension.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(10,1)
y = np.random.rand(10,1)

it = [[1,[128]],[2,(64,128)],[3,(128,64,256)]]
for layers, units in it:
    model = Sequential()
    for i in range(layers):
        model.add(Dense(units[i],input_shape=(1,)))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.summary()
    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='Adam')
    model.fit(x,y,batch_size=1,epochs=1)
```

Comment: Is there any problem when setting input_shape=(1,) in all layers? I mean, in the first layer it is required, but if you keep setting input_shape=(1,) in the later layers I don't imagine how the model would work.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but if you run this code, each model trains without error. Therefore I do not think it uses the input_shape if it is not the first layer. I modified the toy  problem to only have input_shape in the first dimension, and it does not change the number of parameters. Therefore, it does not affect the model. It needs input_shape in the first layer because it has no way of knowing the input shape otherwise, but in subsequent layers, it know the input_shape because the number of units in the upstream layer.